# Show that the truth function $h$ determined by $(A \lor B) \implies \neg C$ generates all truth functions

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Show that the truth function $h$ determined by $(A \lor B) \implies \neg C$ generates all truth functions.

Could someone explain how I would go about proving this, or how I would start? I am having a bit of trouble understanding the question.

Also it's a bit unclear in the book I am using, so could someone please briefly explain how a truth function could possibly generate all truth functions? What does it mean conceptually for a truth function to generate all truth functions?

Comment: Do you know that, for example, $A\land B$ and $\neg A$ together generate all truth functions? Or some small set of "functionally complete" connectives? Other examples are $\{\lor, \neg\}$, $\{\to,\neg\}$. So if you can express both $\land$ and $\neg$ using this $h$ thing, then you've proved the result. Substitute into $h$ and see what you get. For example, what is $((C\lor \neg C)\implies \neg C)$ ?

Comment: @BrianO I understand that every truth function is generated by a statement form involving the connectives ¬, ∧, and ∨. I also understand that by use of tautologies it can be generated by a statement form containing as connectives only ∧ and ¬, or only ∨ and ¬, or only ⇒ and ¬. I think I'm maybe missing something or not understanding something because I still don't see how a single truth function could generate all truth functions? How could our function $h$ alone for example generate a truth function of six statement letters?

Comment: Well, it's not a huge stretch from 2 truth functions generating all of them, to just a single truth function generating all -- right? Do you figure out what truth function $(C\lor \neg C)\implies \neg C$ represents? How can you you represent $(p,q) \mapsto (p\lor q)$ using $h$?

Comment: Ah I understand since $h(C, ¬C, C) = ¬C$ and $h(B, B, ¬C)$ is $B ⇒ C$ and therefore the function *h* can be used to represent these statement forms and therefore used to generate all truth functions using combinations of those two forms? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you got it :)